# Better way of wrapping the result of a monadic-for in an Option, in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, idioms

I want to use Scala's "monadic-for" to obtain, at the end, either Some(x) or None.

This means, that the first element in this monad has to be an Option.

The problem is, that sometimes I don't have an Option to start with.

So I "fake" one, using a dummy value.

The abstract form looks like this:

```
for {
  // only used to yield Some/None at the end
  dummyVal <- Some("dummy value")
  // ...
  // ... other monadic expressions
  // ...
} yield {
  // result which will be wrapped into Some(...)
}
```

A concrete example could be:

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int)

val p = Person("John", 32)
```

At the end this evaluates to `Some("John")`:

```
for {
  dummy <- Some("dummy")
  matchedPerson = p
  if matchedPerson.age > 30
} yield {
  matchedPerson.name
}
```

Whereas this evaluates to `None`:

```
for {
  dummy <- Some("dummy")
  matchedPerson = p
  if matchedPerson.age > 55
} yield {
  matchedPerson.name
}
```

Though I get what I want (a monadic-for that evaluates to `Option`), I have a bad feeling.I had to "misuse" the monadic-for by starting with a "dummy" `Option`, just for the sake of getting `Some`/`None` at the end.

My question is: is there a better way to achieve this, without creating a dummy value?

**UPDATE:**

Consider this example, which builds on the one above:

```
case class Person(name: String, username: String, age: Int)
case class Session(loggedInPerson: Person)

def isValidUser(username: String):Boolean = ???
def isValidPassword(username: String, password: String):Boolean = ???
def readPassword():Option[String] = ???

val usr = Person("John Wayne", "jwayne", 55)

for {
  dummy <- Some("does not matter")
  username = usr.username
  if isValidUser(username)
  pass <- readPassword()
  if isValidPassword(username, pass)
} yield {
  Session(usr)
}
```

Now it's clear that the "for" is pretty long and probably not practicable to re-write using filters, flatMaps, etc.

My goal at the end is to get an `Option[Session]`. I "force" the for to this outcome by starting with a dummy `Some` value.

But as has been pointed out by `Noel M`, I can just rewrite:

```
  dummy <- Some("does not matter")
```

with:

```
  usr <- Some(usr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix for-comprehension, option-boxing and pattern-matching:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p = Person("John", 32)
p: Person = Person(John,32)

scala> for { Person(name, age) <- Option(p); if age > 30} yield name
res0: Option[String] = Some(John)

scala> for { Person(name, age) <- Option(p); if age > 55} yield name
res1: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Using `Option(p)` seems to be even better than my suggested `Some(p)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just do:

```
for {
  person <- Some(p)
  if person.age > 55
} yield person.name
```

?

Though I feel I've misunderstood your question.

Alternatively you could use [**Scalaz**](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day13):

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> case class Person(name:String, age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p = Person("John", 32)
p: Person = Person(John,32)

scala> (p.age > 55) option p.name
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> (p.age > 30) option p.name
res1: Option[String] = Some(John)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Wrapping the object in a Some() and continue with that seems like a better approach (than wrapping over a dummy value).

Comment: I recommend to use `Option(p)` instead of `Some(p)`, will protect you from the case when p is `null`

Answer (score 1):

`Scalaz` has a nice approach as @Noel mentioned, but using pure scala you can use:

```
Option(p).filter( _.age > 55).map(_.name)   // None
Option(p).filter( _.age > 30).map(_.name)   // Some(john)
```

or, all in one:

```
Option(p).collectFirst{ case Person(name, age) if age > 55 => name}
```

It has the advantage that'll also work when `p` is `null`.

Comment: Even if this is possible, my question is specifically related to the for-form, since I am supposing that I will have a long-ish list of "conditions" inside of it... But thanks for showing an alternate way!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand this question. Does this help ?

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age:Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p = Person("John", 32)
p: Person = Person(John,32)

scala> PartialFunction.condOpt(p){case Person(name, age) if age > 55 => name}
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> PartialFunction.condOpt(p){case Person(name, age) if age > 30 => name}
res1: Option[String] = Some(John)
```

Comment: It helps in the particular case for my example, but I'm not sure if it applies to (or is practical with) a longer case where I would have a longer chain inside my for.